# Meaning of night light color temperature

Tags: colors, night-light

Does "night light" block all of the blue lights? or is it related to the color temperature? What is the purpose of color temperature? Does color temperature gradually block the blue lights, such as when the highest color temperature blocks all of the blue lights? or the color temperature doesn't have any relation to the blue lights? Can it filter all of the blue lights if I enable night light and set the color temperature to minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Night light is a feature that reduces the amount of blue light emitted by the screen. Blue light is a type of light that can suppress the production of melatonin, a hormone that helps regulate sleep. By reducing the amount of blue light emitted by the screen, night light can help to improve sleep quality.

Night light typically works by shifting the color temperature of the screen to warmer hues. This can be done manually or automatically, depending on the settings of the computer. Typically, one can regulate the intensity by which the blue light is reduced according to preference.

A more technical explanation of the concept of color temperature can be found on, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature).

Comment: So setting the minimum value to 1000 will completely reduce the blue light? but it was said that 4000–5500 are the optimal values of the color temperature. If it's possible, I wanted to get the scientific reasoning behind the optimal settings.

Comment: I cannot help you with the scientific reasoning. To see what the settings do, one can inspect the source code. To then learn about the rationale for the choices made, one would probably need to ask the developpers if there are no comments in the source code. General more technical rationale of how this works probably can be found on the internet, but it will not be exact science. The general idea is to reduce the intensity of blue frequencies. What is optimal is probably variable and individual.